# Extract an SQL Server 2005 database's structure to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, export

This is something I know can be done *somehow*, because I've done it before, but I can't for the life of me remember how.

I want to export the *structure* of an SQL Server database to an XML file.  The one that I have from last time we did this has this kind of structure:

```
<Data>
    <Details>
        <Server>Server Name</Server>
        <Database>Database Name</Database>
    </Details>
    <Tables>
        <Table>
            <Name>Table Name</Name>
            <Columns>
                <Column>
                    <Colname>Column Name</Colname>
                </Column>
            </Columns>
        </Table>
    </Tables>
    <Procedures>
        <Procedure>
            <Name>Procedure Name</name>
            <Definition>Full text of script</Definition>
        </Procedure>
    </Procedures>
</Data>
```

...And so on.  Does anyone know where to find this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha.  It wasn't a built in feature after all - we use SQL Delta (http://www.sqldelta.com/), and its "Snapshot" feature was what was used.

Answer (score 2):

[DatabaseSpy](http://www.altova.com/databasespy_export_import.html) can do this and has a 30-day trial.

Per comment:  You might be able to do it with [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) and you could certainly do it with some [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137(SQL.90).aspx) queries against the system tables.

Comment: See, it's weird - because I'm pretty sure that we just used built in SQL Server tools, but I can't remember which ones.  I've looked through the Import & Export Wizard, which is where I'd think it would be, but I can't see it there.